# Prove a set is open with respect to a metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given a metric $d$ in a set $M$, let $d'(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1 \}$ for $x,y\in M$

Prove that a set $U\subseteq M$ is open with respect to $d$ if and only if it is open with respect to $d'$.

The proof of "if $U\subseteq M$ is open with respect to $d$, then it is open with respect to $d'$" follows quickly because $d'(x,y)\le d(x,y)$.

But I am having problems with "if $U\subseteq M$ is open with respect to $d'$, then it is open with respect to $d$"

So assuming that $U\subseteq M$ is open with respect to $d'$ implies that for all $x\in U$ there exists $r>0$ such that $y\in M$, $d'(x,y)<r$ implies that $y\in U$.

So if $d(x,y)\le 1$ then $d'(x,y)=d(x,y)$ so $d(x,y)<r$ and therefore open.

Now I am unsure how to proceed for the case $d(x,y)> 1 = d'(x,y)$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/948756/4280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only point that you’re missing is this one: if $d'(x,y)<r$ implies that $y\in U$, and $s<r$, then $d'(x,y)<s$ also implies that $y\in U$. Thus, you might as well assume that $r\le 1$, and everything falls into place.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However I don't understand how $r\le 1$ implies that $d(x,y)<r$

Comment: @Burgundy: I didn’t say that $r\le 1$ implies that $d(x,y)<r$. I said that if $r$ is small enough to ensure that $B_{d'}(x,r)\subseteq U$, and $s<r$, then $B_{d'}(x,s)\subseteq U$ as well. If $r$ ‘works’, you can replace it by any smaller positive radius. Thus, you can always find an $r\le 1$ such that $B_{d'}(x,r)\subseteq U$. This **not** the same as saying that $B_{d'}(x,r)\subseteq U$ for **all** $r\le 1$.

Comment: Ok thank you for clearifying. However, I do not see how this can aid in showing that $U$ Is open with respect to $d$

Comment: @Burgundy: You're welcome. Just use the fact that if $r\ le 1$, then $B_d(x,r)=B_{d'}(x,r)$, so that if one of these open balls is contained in $U$, so is the other.